# invalid instruction suffix for mov?

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

I have this piece of inline assembly code that should print A in text mode:

```
    void print(){
        asm volatile(
            "mov ax,0xb800\n"
            "mov ds,ax\n" /*<-as complains about this*/
            "movb 0,'A'\n"
    ); 
}
```

However when I try to compile it with gcc(with -m32 and -masm=intel):

```
./source/kernel.c: Assembler messages:
./source/kernel.c:4: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `mov'
```

btw this piece of code is from my operating system's kernel, so I can't use stdio.h or something like that.

Comment: Are you sure that is the right assembly syntax? Syntax can vary with assembler.

Comment: I use Intel syntax ,and I already added -masm=intel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite GCC's line numbering in the error message, that's not the line it's actually complaining about, it's the `movb` store.  You can test that by commenting the other instructions.  The error is actually printed by the assembler, with numbering based on `.loc` metadata directives from the compiler, and this is a multi-line asm template, so it's easy for that to go wrong I guess.

I suspect GAS `.intel_syntax` mode treats a literal `0` as an immediate, for consistency with `mov al, 0` with `0` as a source operand.  This of course can't work as a destination.

The "invalid instruction suffix" error message makes little sense, although note that Intel syntax doesn't use operand-size suffixes.  (For some reason `movb [0], 'A'` is accepted, though.)

Instead use square brackets to avoid ambiguity; recommended for *any* memory operand, even if the address is a symbol instead of a literal number.

```
    mov  byte ptr [0], 'A'
```

`mov  byte ptr ds:0, 'A'` also works, and is the syntax `objdump -d -Mintel` uses.

It's a good idea to always use square brackets on memory operands to remove any ambiguity, especially for people who might be used to the NASM flavour of Intel syntax.

Comment: From https://wiki.osdev.org/GAS#Intel_Syntax_Support : "It is generally discouraged to use the support for Intel Syntax because it can subtly and surprisingly different than the real Intel Syntax found in other assemblers". It's possible the `0` token may be taken as an immediate value even though that would be impossible in that position - both `ds:0` and `[0]` would change its nature. Just guessing but it does make a little sense.

Comment: @paxdiablo: yeah, looking like an immediate was my guess at why it was rejected and why I tried `ds:0` and `[0]` to see if they'd work.  And mostly agreed with that sentiment; use GNU `.intel_syntax` as a read-only format for stuff like objdump / gdb / gcc asm output unless you don't mind figuring out how to work around occasional design quirks in GAS's intel syntax.  But if you really must use GNU C Extended inline asm (instead of writing a stand-alone function in NASM), it's a valid option for personal projects for sure.  Glibc and Linux sources only use AT&T, though.